# Piano finger apparatus in history or film

Tags: piano, fingering, composers

Can anyone recall the movie where a piano player was using an apparatus to strengthen (or stretch) their ring finger. I keep picturing AMADEUS but i can't find references. If not, does any one know of a piano player who was documented as having used such tools.The tool had a string and pulley.

Comment: I believe this should be over at Movies SE

Answer (score 1):

Robert Schumann supposedly injured his hand with a device designed to strengthen the fourth finger.

http://ericsams.org/index.php/on-music/essays/on-schumann/116-schumann-s-hand-injury-some-further-evidence

His hand was injured but the actual injury has now acquired the patina of legend.